# A shorter non-repeating alphanumeric code than UUID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cryptography

Is it possible for MySQL database to generate a 5 or 6 digit code comprised of only numbers and letters when I insert a record? If so how?

Just like goo.gl, bit.ly and jsfiddle do it. For exaple:

- http://bit.ly/**3PKQcJ**
- http://jsfiddle.net/**XzKvP**

**cZ6ahF, 3t5mM, xGNPN, xswUdS...**

So `UUID_SHORT()` will not work because it returns a value like `23043966240817183`

### Requirements:

1. **Must** be unique (non-repeating)
2. Can be but not required to be based off of primary key integer value
3. **Must** scale (grow by one character when all possible combinations have been used)
4. **Must** look random. (item `1234` cannot be `BCDE` while item `1235` be `BCDF`)
5. **Must** be generated on insert.

Would greatly appreciate code examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do sites like goo.gl or jsfiddle generate their URL codes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299901/how-do-sites-like-goo-gl-or-jsfiddle-generate-their-url-codes)

Comment: Why the constraint "Must be generated on insert."?

Comment: @JoeFrambach To minimize the "back and forth" example. So I can do everything in ONE shot instead of: Insert, return primary key, generate code using primary key as seed, update transaction with generated code.

Comment: I think you're asking for too much.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I saw another post, they guy was doing it. But the question was not exactly related to HOW he was doing it so he did not have the solution. But he did say it was a funtion he made that generated the code at the time the PK was generated. I appreciate your effort. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link please?

Comment: @JoeFrambach The "duplicate" question is a C# solution. This is a mySQL solution. Please read carefully.

Comment: Well good luck, I'm out.

Comment: @JoeFrambach http://stackoverflow.com/a/5886175/442580

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(UUID(), 6);
```

Comment: (+1) I like the simplicity though I'm concerned about the uniqueness of it. After a billion entries I'm bound to have some collisions. Plus it does not scale. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: What do you mean it *"does not scale"*? Replace `6` with `7` or `8` or `12`. That's the definition of "scale".

Comment: @ypercube As I said `grow by one character when all possible combinations have been used`. This should not have to be done manually. It should scale on it's own without manual intervention. Also it is not unique. Eventually there will be a collision.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Redis for this task, actually. It has all the features that make this task suitable for its use. Foremost, it is very good at searching a big list for a value.

We will create two lists, `buffered_ids`, and `used_ids`. A cronjob will run every 5 minutes (or whatever interval you like), which will check the length of `buffered_ids` and keep it above, say, 5000 in length. When you need to use an id, pop it from `buffered_ids` and add it to `used_ids`.

Redis has `sets`, which are unique items in a collection. Think of it as a hash where the keys are unique and all the values are "true".

Your cronjob, in bash:

```
log(){ local x=$1 n=2 l=-1;if [ "$2" != "" ];then n=$x;x=$2;fi;while((x));do let l+=1 x/=n;done;echo $l; }
scale=`redis-cli SCARD used_ids`
scale=`log 16 $scale`
scale=$[ scale + 6]
while [ `redis-cli SCARD buffered_ids` -lt 5000 ]; do
    uuid=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "[:alnum:]" | head -c ${1:-$scale}`
    if [ `redis-cli SISMEMBER used_ids $uuid` == 1]; then
        continue
    fi
    redis-cli SADD buffered_ids $uuid
done
```

To grab the next uid for use in your application (in pseudocode because you did not specify a language)

```
$uid = redis('SPOP buffered_ids');
redis('SADD used_ids ' . $uid);
```

**edit** actually there's a race condition there. To safely pop a value, add it to used_ids first, then remove it from buffered_ids.

```
$uid = redis('SRANDMEMBER buffered_ids');
redis('SADD used_ids ' . $uid);
redis('SREM buffered_ids ' . $uid);
```

Comment: I've edited so the scale automatically increases as more items are added!

Comment: Edited for random alphas, rather than uuid with outputs hyphens

Comment: Thanks Joe, but I'm looking for a MySQL solution/function based on a pseudo random permutation or something that will allow me to skip the needles seeking for duplicates. I might have considered this but using Redis is simply not an option for me in my current environment.